# I am trying to do mle for school assignment, why could I be getting this error:

Tags: python

```
#1) Find best fitting distribution parameters
best_fit(macamil2data) 
#     {'loglaplace': {'c': 1.0603278885766216,
#                     'loc': -0.04671203840594998,
#                     'scale': 10.230045114772532}}

#2) Calculate pdf using said parameters
def loglaplace_loglikelihood(params, data):
    c, loc, scale = params
    return stats.loglaplace.logpdf(data, c=c, loc=loc, scale=scale).sum()

#3) Minimize using said parameters
initial_params = [1.0603278885766216, -0.04671203840594998, 10.230045114772532]
results = minimize(loglaplace_loglikelihood, initial_params, args=(macamil2data))

print(results)

 message: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
  success: False
   status: 2
      fun: nan
        x: [ 5.127e+03 -1.765e+05 -1.945e+03]
      nit: 2
      jac: [       nan        nan        nan]
 hess_inv: [[ 6.876e-01 -1.388e+01  5.195e-02]
            [-1.388e+01  5.437e+02  5.473e+00]
            [ 5.195e-02  5.473e+00  1.000e+00]]
     nfev: 464
     njev: 116

macamil2data=
0.916666
1
3.3
3.38333
3.68333
4.16667
4.2
6.08333
6.61667
7.03333
7.5
7.85
8.15
9.08333
9.35
10.0833
10.1833
10.4333
11.2833
14.2
16.5333
20.0333
23.8333
30.35
30.5167
32.4667
37.1
40.8167
45.6
52
70.0667
70.5333
85.2333
130.967
```

Comment: [Cross-posted on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77878617)